# Google OAuth and Zend connect using my application's credentials

Tags: zend-framework, google-api, youtube-api, oauth-2.0, zend-gdata

My website allows users to upload videos to MY youtube account. To connect my aplication to Google (youtube) I used the component ClientLogin like this:

```
//my credentials
$user = 'mymail@gmail.com';
$pass = 'mypass';
$service = 'youtube';
$developerKey = 'mydevkey';

//create the http client
$httpClient = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, $service, null,
                Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::DEFAULT_SOURCE,null,null,
                Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::CLIENTLOGIN_URI,'GOOGLE');
$httpClient->setHeaders('X-GData-Key', 'key='. $developerKey);

//create the instances
$youTubeService = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient);
$newVideoEntry = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry();
$newVideoEntry->setVideoTitle("test video");
$newVideoEntry->setVideoDescription("just testing");
$newVideoEntry->setVideoCategory("Music");
$newVideoEntry->setVideoTags('test, api');

//call the API to get the upload url and token
$tokenHandlerUrl = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/action/GetUploadToken';
try {
    $tokenArray = $youTubeService->getFormUploadToken($newVideoEntry, $tokenHandlerUrl);
} catch (Exception $e) {

}
$tokenValue = $tokenArray['token'];
$postUrl = $tokenArray['url'];
```

But now ClientLogin is deprecated :S, and I need to use oAuth 2... but have been reading the documentation and it says nothing about connecting using my apps credential (not the user's credentials). Is there a way to reproduce this code but using oAuth?

Comment: I am also trying to find a solution for this. How did you managed to get it done?

Comment: I had to do it like this, for now. I've read that ClientLogin will still be [available until 2015](https://developers.google.com/accounts/terms), so it's ok for now I guess, until I find a better solution

Comment: Yeah, I guess that info it's right: https://developers.google.com/accounts/terms . Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, the way to do this with OAuth2 is with a service account:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Once the account is set up in your API console, it then allows for server-to-server interactions. Unfortunately, the Youtube API doesn't yet support service accounts:

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2#Service_Accounts

Hopefully this support will come soon (at the very least before ClientLogin goes away!)